# Python - Hello, i'm new to python, i have a problem with a variable not updating in a while loop, When i do it just outputs "hello" infinitely

Tags: python

This is the code--

```
while True:
    spam = 0
    spam + 1
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        print('Greetings!')
        break
```

What i want it to do is output
"Hello" first, then "Howdy" second and after the third time it output "Greetings" and breaks the code.
However the code loops infinitely with "Hello" being the output
Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to declare `spam` outside the while loop so that it does not get reinitilalized to 0 every time. Also, make sure you reassign `spam` to `spam + 1`:

```
spam = 0
while True:
    spam += 1
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        print('Greetings!')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, initialize *spam* outside the loop.
Secondly, you might have missed a "=" so you are not updating *spam*.
The correct code should looks like this:

```
spam = 0
while True:
  spam += 1
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why its failing is because:

```
spam = 0
```

^ is initialized inside the loop, hence with every iteration, the value of `spam` is set to `0`. Also `spam + 1` does not modify `spam`

Take the var initializing part outside the loop and increment to it after the iteration:

```
spam = 1            # could be set to spam = 0
while True:
    # spam += 1       # uncomment if spam is set to 0 at top
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        print('Greetings!')
        break
    spam += 1                       # used when spam = 1 at top
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you write the spam variable inside the while loop if you write it outside it will work fine.

```
spam = 0
while True: 
    spam += 1
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        print('Greetings!')
        break
```

Comment: This would still fail.

Comment: I edited the code. You can check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spam = 0
a = True
while a is True:
    spam += 1
    if spam == 1:
        print('Hello')
    elif spam == 2:
        print('Howdy')
    else:
        a = False
        print('Greetings!')
```

Comment: @DirtyBit it's running on mine. Try again maybe there is an indent error